# Setting up Ethernet in My Apartment

Tags: networking, router, internet, ethernet

I recently moved to an apartment where both the router and modem are not in the same room as my PC. Like most apartment complexes, we are required to have our own internet service which means connecting the modem to the phone jack, and then the router to the modem using the designated internet port.

[image: internet port]

Also, there are several wall ports around the unit which the modem is attached to.

[image: wall ports]

Instead of purchasing a really long ethernet cable, I'd like to utilize the ethernet wall ports provided throughout the apartment but don't really know where to start.

Is it possible to hook my router up to the ethernet jack directly in my dining room, then connect my PC to a completely different ethernet jack that's inside my room?

I've actually already attempted this but to no success. I saw a YouTube video suggesting I find a "master jack" that if the router attached to, all the ports within my unit would connect to the router via Ethernet.

After searching on Google, I saw that this was only a UK thing. Is there something similar here in the US or is it typically just a port-to-port kind of thing? I can't really unscrew the wall plate off without breaking the paint seal so I can't do much investigative work.

Edit: I also have some designated Ethernet wall outlets that just have the Ethernet socket (labeled with CAT5E) and my Ethernet cables do fit. I also updated the second picture to what the current wall port my router & modem is attached to. Modem -> COAX cable, router -> ethernet

Comment: Those ports (with the COAX cables coming out) aren't Ethernet - they are for phone lines, and for sharing TV signals (such that only one antenna is needed for many apartments). You cannot share Ethernet through this, even if you wanted to - there simply aren't enough wires for Ethernet to be duplicated across rooms. You're better off using a single router and using Wireless, OR, a Powerline adapter. Powerline adapters can be very useful, but you may get a shaky connection, as you share the Earth connection with other apartments.

Comment: Addition: If those ports really _are_ ethernet ports (i.e. the ethernet cables do fit) then it means a dedicated ethernet switch has been set up by the apartment. This is good news, and it means you should only have to connect an Ethernet cable between your router (any one of the ethernet ports - NOT the internet port) and the wall socket, and the other wall sockets should work. It appears from the photo in the second link that it looks like a phone socket, but it _could_ be an Ethernet one too - i've only just realised this.

Comment: It is possible to carry Ethernet data over coax using MoCA converters, but I'm not sure how well that works in an apartment where the coax connectors go who knows where.

Comment: "Master jack", however, just...doesn't make any sense for Ethernet ports. That's not how Ethernet works. Not switched Ethernet (where connections only have two ends) and not even obsolete bus Ethernet.

Comment: @grawity that's what I thought, it didn't really make sense to me but apparently master jacks is a thing in the UK or at least with one specific company

Comment: @QuickishFM I made an edit to the original post, I actually do have designated ethernet ports and i updated the phone jack cable picture. Could you expand on what the "internet port" is? are they the ports with the COAX cables poking out that you previously mentioned?

Comment: @hellofren the Internet port, or WAN port, is on the router and connects to the modem, and to the modem only. That's where the Internet supply comes from, and won't work if you connect a computer to it, even if the port is the same. There are other ethernet ports on the router (LAN ports) which are for the computers and powrline adapters etc.

Comment: Since the wall port is labelled cat5e, I believe it's already internally switched. Just connect any one of the 4 Ethernet LAN ports from the router, to the wall ports. The other wall ports should then work.

Comment: @QuickishFM oh sorry, I forgot for a second what the internet port was, lol. I knew what it was for 3seconds when I made the post. I tried connecting an ethernet cable from the router to the wall port then a wall port in my room to my PC but still no wired connection :(.

Comment: Those ethernet ports are either all connected to a central unit - ethernet switch, which you'd have to find & make sure it's working - or they're all point to point & you have to find the correct 'other end' of each one.

Comment: Maybe, in relation to what QuickishFM said about "internally switched" (which also isn't a thing), there's a central place in the apartment where all the wall jacks go into an Ethernet patch panel, and there's a dusty old Ethernet switch hidden in there that is currently powered off?

Comment: Easiest way to find is to ask your landlord or the neighbours (they'll have similar apartments). There should be a place somewhere where all these port end, once you look at that you should know what to do. Easiest way to find out if the ports are for ethernet or phone is to open the wall socket up and look inside.

Comment: @grawity sorry for any confusion; by Internally Switched, I meant it was switched somewhere else in the apartment complex, and not directly wired to every switch identically (in parallel, like power wires are, for example). For ethernet to work, it must be switched. As Tetsujin said, the ethernet switch for OPs apartment might not be working.

Comment: @hellofren, did you ever find the other end to these cables, or get any further with this? My flat in the UK is similar, it is driving me mad that I can't find the other end of these cables...

Comment: The property manager pointed me to my internet service provider saying that it's my ISP's responsibility to "set it up." Then my ISP pointed back to my apartment, so no luck actually getting anything done. It's funny that they have these ethernet jacks throughout the unit that don't even work.

It was my property manager's fault that it didn't work, and they were too incompetent to fix it nor did they want to deal with it.

At the end of the day, we just had a long cable from my computer all the way to the router, the less aesthetic way, but nothing else I could do